# Bind list of complex elements in play framework on AJAX POST

Tags: java, playframework

I have a simple `Foo` class with two attributes and `form` binder:

```
import play.data.Form;

public class Foo {
    public static Form<Foo> form = Form.form(Foo.class);

    public String name;
    public List<Bar> bars = new ArrayList<Bar>();
}
```

Where `Bar` class is:

```
public class Bar {
    public String prop1;
    public String prop2;
}
```

When I try to make POST ajax request:

```
jsRoutes.controllers.Test.duh().ajax({
  data: {
    name: "Test",
    bars: [{prop1: "first"}]
  }
});
```

in duh method, on line:

```
Form<Foo> request = Foo.form.bindFromRequest();
```

I get error:

> [InvalidPropertyException: Invalid property 'bars[0][prop1]' of bean
>   class [models.Foo]: Property referenced in indexed property path
>   'bars[0][prop1]' is neither an array nor a List nor a Map; returned
>   value was [first]]

AJAX request's Form data looks like this:

```
name:Test
bars[0][prop1]:first
```

**Question:** What is a proper way to bind list of complex elements in play framework? What else is needed for this code to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @fjtorres mentioned, problem is with the way how jQuery.param serializes data. Play expects `bars[0].prop1` instead of `bars[0][prop1]`. To go around this problem, I changed the code to the following:

**frontend:**

```
jsRoutes.controllers.Test.duh().ajax({
  data: JSON.stringify({
    name: "Test",
    bars: [{prop1: "first"}]
  }),
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  }
});
```

**backend - controler: duh method:**

```
Form<Foo> request = Foo.form.bind(request().body().asJson());
```

This sends data on backend as a JSON. On backend `JsonNode` is retrieved from request body and passed to form `bind` method.

Answer (score 0):

According indicates playframework web in this [URL](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.2/controllers#binding) (POJO object binding section) the binding for entity list should be **bars[0].prop1**

Comment: That is correct, but ajax request's form data is generated by jQuery. No custom code is used for that. It is play who should take care of it, isn't it?

Comment: Before test sample with RestClient and play application, Play not support this format for list of entities, this format its for Maps. I'm not sure if jquery supports other format for submit list data.

Comment: You could try send data with JSON.stringify(postData)

Comment: That is what I did at the and. I will post my solution as an answer. Anyway, thx a lot.